# How do I apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to find the derivative $F'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

> Let $F(x)$ be the function defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$ by the formula
>   $$F(x)=\int_{-e^x}^{e^{2x}}|t^2-1|\,{\rm d}t$$
>   Find $F'(x)$. Show your work.

So I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, and im getting stuck. I've tried splitting the integral into two seperate functions $u$ and $z$ and then applying the fundamental theorum of calculus to find $F'(x)$.

[image: trial]

However from observing desmos, and using its ability to graph the derivative of a function, my answer appears to only be correct for $x>0$. I was wondering what I need to do to find the answer for $x<0$. Or if my answer is even right at all. Thanks in advance for the help. The absolute value is the main thing throwing me off I think. Here is desmos, with $F(x$), $F'(x)$ and my answer graphed.

[image: desmos]

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

I’ll let $|t^2-1| = g(t)$ for clarity.$$F(x) =\int_{-e^x}^{e^{2x}} g(t) dt$$ By the FTC, we have $$F’(x) = g(e^{2x} ) \ 2e^{2x} - g(-e^x) \ (-e^x) \\ = 2e^{2x}|e^{4x} -1|+e^x|e^{2x} -1| $$ Now, $e^{kx} -1 \lt 0 $ for $x\lt 0$, and positive otherwise. $$\therefore F’(x) = \begin{cases} 2e^{6x} -2e^{2x} +e^{3x} -e^x , \ \text{if} \  x\lt 0 \\ -2e^{6x} +2e^{2x} -e^{3x} +e^x , \ \text{if} \ x\ge 0 \end{cases} $$